# I need to create a dictionary that counts the number of times a name appears in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I have this code so far:

```
def name_counts(name_list):
    name_dict = {}
    for word in name_list:
        if word in name_dict:
            name_dict[word] += 1
        else:
            name_dict[word] = 1


print(name_counts(name_list))
```

which is resulting in:

but I need it to only print the first names, not the lasts. How would I do that? I know that I should use the split function but anytime I do `name_list.split()` it returns with an attribute error.

Comment: `Counter(list)`

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: im sorry this is my first time posting here and I didnt know how to enter code into the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a temporary variable at the start of the `for` loop which would contain the split name, like so:

```
for word in name_list:
  name = word.split()[0]
  if name in name_dict:
    name_dict[name] += 1
  else:
    name_dict[name] = 0
```

Note that the `.split()` function returns a `list`, so to get the first name, you have to get the item at index `0`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Whenever i used split i would forget to index it, so that was my problem

Answer (score 1):

The [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the collection module does just that! You can use:

```
from collections import Counter
# get firstname from name
print(Counter(firstname))
```

EDIT: I'll let you figure out how to parse the firstname :)

Answer (score 1):

You are very close! What you are doing in your function right now is just looking at the full name, while the directions say you should just be looking at the first name and seeing how much it appeared. what you should have is something like this. While looking through each word in the loop, make an array, lets say `name` and set it to `word.split()`. Then like in your following code, check if `name[0]` (the first name) exists in the list, and increment `name_dict[name[0]]` if it does. If not, make a new key with `name[0]` and set it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in a single line using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
>>>from collections import Counter
>>>name_list = ["Davy Jones", "Davy Crockett", "George Washington"]
>>>Counter([name.split()[0] for name in name_list])
#result -->
Counter({'Davy': 2, 'George': 1})
```